# How to get all Invoices of logged in customers in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-account, invoice

I want to display the list of invoices of logged in customer in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the invoice for specific customer in the following

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session; 
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactoryInterface; 
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;


/**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactoryInterface
     */
    private $orderCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config
     */
    protected $_orderConfig;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config $orderConfig,
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_orderConfig = $orderConfig;
    }
```

Use this code in the function you want to display invoice

```
$orders =$this->getOrders();
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
            foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
                var_dump($invoice->getData());
            }
        }
```

These are the function which has been used in the above code

```
/**
     * @return CollectionFactoryInterface
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.1
     */
    private function getOrderCollectionFactory()
    {
        if ($this->orderCollectionFactory === null) {
            $this->orderCollectionFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(CollectionFactoryInterface::class);
        }
        return $this->orderCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        if (!($customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->orders) {
            $this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
        }
        return $this->orders;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: i will try and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory as InvoiceCollectionFactory;
```

Now di inject:

```
public function __construct(
    InvoiceCollectionFactory $invoiceCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->invoiceCollectionFactory = $invoiceCollectionFactory;
}
```

How you use:

```
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection $invoiceCollection */
$invoiceCollection = $this->invoiceCollectionFactory->create();
$invoiceCollection->getSelect()
    ->join(
        'sales_order',
        'sales_order.entity_id=main_table.order_id'
    )
    ->where('customer_id=?', 1);
```

Comment: @Rana i will try and let u know.

Comment: @Rana How to pass customer id dynamically based on logged in customer ?

Comment: You can get it from session. Magento\Customer\Model\Session